# OpenLayers Vector Tile Info

Tags: openlayers, popup, mapping

I've created a map and I am using Openlayers Vector Tile Info example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-info.html
to retrieve the point information from GeoServer.

My code is as follows:

```
// WFS Layer
layer_wfs = new ol.layer.Vector(
{
source: new ol.source.Vector(
{
format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
url: 'http://[URL as required]
}
),
title: 'WFS Layer',
visible: false,
style: new ol.style.Style(
    {
        image: new ol.style.Circle(
        {
            radius: 6,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke(
            {
                color: [255, 219, 77],
                width: 2
            }
            ),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill(
            {
                color: [255, 255, 0, 0.6]
            }
            )
        }
    )
    }
    )
}
);

// Create a view
myview = new ol.View(
{
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-6.67, 54.15], "EPSG:3857"),
zoom: 7,
projection: 'EPSG:3857'
}
); 

// Create a map
map = new ol.Map(
{
target: 'map',
interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate:false, pinchRotate:false }),
layers:[layer_wfs],
view: myview,
controls:[
new ol.control.Zoom(),
new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
new ol.control.LayerSwitcher()
]
}
);

map.on('pointermove', showInfo);

var info = document.getElementById('info');
function showInfo(event) {
  var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
  if (features.length == 0) {
    info.innerText = '';
    info.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }
  var properties = features[0].getProperties();
  info.innerText = JSON.stringify(properties, null, 2);
  info.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

This brings up the information perfectly, however it seems to be bringing up additional information which I'm not sure how to get rid off (or why it's there as it isn't stored in the attribute table). I only want the Address, Postcode, X and Y coordinate information to appear - how do I get rid of the rest?

[image: strong text]

Comment: As you have a vector layer instead of a vector tile layer the properties include the geometry object.  There are many way in JavaScript to get a subset of your properties object which includes only the keys which you wish to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm new to all of this, so I don't really understand the thread you've attached or where to alter my own JS code

Answer (score 2):

This should work on any browser

```
  var properties = features[0].getProperties();
  var subset = {
    Address: properties.Address,
    Postcode: properties.Postcode,
    X_Coordina: properties.X_Coordina,
    Y_Coordina: properties.Y_Coordina
  };
  info.innerText = JSON.stringify(subset, null, 2);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @AmyOKeefe If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems knot that problem was resolved.